# Vibrator Manager and Camera Manager (32 API)

Tags: android, kotlin

My app is 32 android API target, i could not use Vibrator manager with neither Camera Manger
i dont know what is the problem with both i did a lot of research im trying to use the camera without a preview using surface i want to run it (both cameras) in background but there is no background service manager, i used multiple emulator as it maybe a pixel bug for
CameraManager but still the same problem.

CameraManager Problem:

> Process: com.amjadshuk.roadanalysia, PID: 2971
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: supportsCameraApi:2340: Unknown camera ID camera1

VibratorManager problem:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amjadshuk.roadanalysia/com.amjadshuk.roadanalysia.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.os.VibratorManager

### Codes:

Vibrator Manager :

```kt
val vb = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
vb.vibrate(CombinedVibration.createParallel(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1000,VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)))
```

Camera Manager :

```kt
private fun camera1() {
    val cm = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    val cc : CameraDevice.StateCallback = object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        override fun onOpened(p0: CameraDevice) {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView29).text = "CameraDevice is open"
        }

        override fun onDisconnected(p0: CameraDevice) {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView29).text = "CameraDevice is Disconnected"

        }

        override fun onError(p0: CameraDevice, p1: Int) {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView29).text = "CameraDevice is Error"

        }

    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        this.requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA),15478)
    }

    try {

        cm.openCamera("camera1", mainExecutor, cc)
    } catch (e : CameraAccessException) {

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView29).text = e.message.toString()
        Log.d("camera1", "camera1: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`val vb = this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager`

or pass the appropriate context to the class via constructor and then get the service

`val vb = context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager`

Answer (score -1):

For `CameraManger` don't put a string like I did `"Camera1"` it is wrong, id must be initialized from `CameraManager.cameraIdList` which represents all cameras connected to the device, I have solved yeeeey!

I have used my initialized CameraManager (cm) and put

```
cm.openCamera(cm.cameraIdList.first(), mainExecutor, cc)
```

instead of

```
cm.openCamera("Camera1", mainExecutor, cc)
```

source:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager#getCameraIdList()

I still did not solve the `VibratorManager` thing I cant cast non-nullable object by as or something.